# MSI Inno Parameter Passing Correctly

Tags: windows-installer

I spent time searching for an answer but still can't quite figure this out.

I have this MSI file that I can run this command to silent install it.

```
msiexec.exe /i theapp.msi /q INSTALLDIR=C:\myapp CLIENTDATA=34542@localhost.com
```

With Inno, I attempted the following and my MSI will not silently install.  What I do receive is this window [image] will pop up automatically so obvious there is a probleming passing the commands to the msiexec process.

```
#define MyAppName "fooApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "fooUser"
#define MyAppURL "http://foo.com"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{E633BAE8-81C7-4190-9964-D86287FAA8F4}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
CreateAppDir=no
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
ShowTasksTreeLines=True

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "D:\theapp.msi"; DestDir: "    {tmp}";
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i /q CLIENTDATA=34542@localhost.com    {tmp}\theapp.msi"""; Flags: runascurrentuser shellexec
```

Underneath the [Run] section if I use this line I the MSI is launched correctly in interactive mode where the user will fill in the parameters manually which I don't want the m doing.

```
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\theapp.msi"""
```

In another post, I saw someone mention to use this function but I couldn't find any sample code on how to actually use it.

```
function ParamStr(Index: Integer):
```

Thanks for any direction here.

Comment: Since posting this one solution that I figured out is to use this command

Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i {tmp}\theapp.msi /qb CLIENTDATA=34542@localhost.com"; Flags: runascurrentuser shellexec

I am curious what other ways there are to do this.

Comment: Convert your comment to the answer since you figured it out. By the way, what is the point in using Inno Setup to install MSI?

Comment: The MSI was given to me by a third party and the requirement given was that I had to use INNO to pass in parameters and automatically do things automatically after the MSI was installed but before the INNO setup was done.

Personally, I wanted to use Qwerty.MSI to hard code everything in the MSI directly but that wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I figured out how to do what I wanted to do.

```
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i {tmp}\theapp.msi /qb CLIENTDATA=34542@localhost.com"; Flags: runascurrentuser shellexec
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "/passive" parameter on "msiexec.exe" line.

Example:
Source: "D:\Onedrive\vbfiles\InstaladorCrystal\CRRedist2005_x86.msi"; DestDir: {tmp}; CopyMode: alwaysoverwrite;

Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\CRRedist2005_x86.msi"" **/passive**"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}"; StatusMsg: "Installing Crystal Reports 32bits..."; Check: not IsWin64(); Flags: skipifsilent